# Exception not caught when loading an assembly and calling a function with reflection

Tags: c#, exception

So I have a test that load an assembly, get a specific class and run a function. It works fine except that if I get an exception inside the class I can't catch it.

In the test I start with to create a new Appdomain like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    [Test, TestCaseSource("FromFile")]
    public void AutomationTest(string testCasePath)
    {
        var pathToDll = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string assemblyPath = ...
        AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup
        {
            PrivateBinPath = pathToDll
        };
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TempDomain", null, domainSetup);
        InstanceProxy proxy = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, typeof(InstanceProxy).FullName) as InstanceProxy;
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            proxy.LoadLibrary(assemblyPath);
        }
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    }
```

Then I call on my class like this:

```
    internal class InstanceProxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void LoadLibrary(string path)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            Type[] types = asm.GetExportedTypes();
            Type type = types.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.FullName == "MyNamespace.SomeClass"));
            if (type != null)
            {
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
                try
                {
                    obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                        Type.DefaultBinder, obj, null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Assert.Fail(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I get an exception the code will stop to run at my InvokeMember even when I have a try/catch. Is there some way to get around this?

Update 1:

I Tried to change LoadLibrary to this as João Mendes said:

```
        public void LoadLibrary(string path)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            Type[] types = asm.GetExportedTypes();
            Type type = types.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.FullName == "MyNamespace.SomeClass"));
            if (type != null)
            {
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                var method = type.GetMethod("Run");
                try
                {
                    method.Invoke(obj, null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Assert.Fail(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

But still breaks inside the try.

Comment: If you are running this in the debugger, that is exactly how it is supposed to work. Exceptions pause the debugger so you can see where the exception happened. You can go into your Debug>Exceptions and uncheck that specific exception and it should continue into your catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some looking (and comment from Ron Beyer I found the solution).

First I simply went to Debug > Window > Exception settings and and unchecked all Break when thrown. This didn't solve the kind of exception I had thought.

Then when I run the software again and saw that the exception window had it's own checkbox (something similiar to "break when thrown"), so I unchecked it and now it run perfectly without me seeing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Instead of `InvokeMember`, use `GetMethod("Run")` to get a reference to a `MethodInfo` object, then use that to call `Invoke(obj, null)`.

That way, you don't have to mess with binders and binding flags, and you also get a nice `TargetInvocationException` you can catch.

Comment: That would have been beautiful, but sadly it didn't work. I updated with the code I tried with and it did still break inside the try.